# c program for directory monitor

Tags: c

i want c program for directory monitor

Comment: I want a C program for world domination. I can has?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490754/code-for-directory-monitor-using-unix-concepts-in-c-language

Comment: It is best to do some work, then ask a specific question if you get stuck. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: MS developed a C program for world domination. Just a few more bugs to work out...

Answer (score 3):

Use [`inotify`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).